# Need to fetch a list of customer's customerID having same first_name from mongoDB Atlas from a java application using java 3.12.0 driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

By using the following code i am able to get the list of customer objects having same first_name, but for my next operation i only need the `customerID`s of all the fetched customers, instead i am only getting the first fetched `customerID` for all objects. can anyone please help?

```
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb+srv://sumitraojha:<pwd>@cluster0-tkx83.mongodb.net/customer?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
System.out.println("The connection to mongoDB is established");

//MongoDB Customer Database connection
MongoDatabase cust_database = mongoClient.getDatabase("customer");
System.out.println("The connection to Database\t"+cust_database.getName()+"\tis established successfully");
//System.out.println("the database is "+cust_database.getName());

//Displaying the Queried Document
System.out.println("\n Enter the customer Name to search:\n ");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String fname = sc.next();
System.out.println("\n The Customer Details are:");
MongoCollection<Document> newcustDetails = cust_database.getCollection("NewCustomerDetails");

MongoCursor<Document> custcursor1 = newcustDetails.find(eq("first_name", fname)).iterator(); 
//System.out.println(custcursor1); 
ArrayList<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();
try { 
    while(custcursor1.hasNext()) 
    { 

    System.out.println("\n"+custcursor1.next().toJson());
    String temp = newcustDetails.find().projection(Projections.include("CustomerID")).first().getString("CustomerID");
    System.out.println(temp);
    value.add(temp);
    } 

    } 
    finally { 
              // TODO: handle finally clause
              custcursor1.close(); 
              }
System.out.println("\n The Customer ID are:\t\t");
    Iterator<String> i1=value.iterator();  
    while(i1.hasNext())  
    {  
        System.out.println(i1.next());  
    }
```

[this is the output i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNlXd.png)

Comment: The statement `custcursor1.next()` returns a `Document` object. You can use the [Document](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/org/bson/Document.html) class's `get` method to extract the `CustomerID` from the current document. For example, `document.get("CustomerId")` will return the customer id value as a string. There is no need for the additional `find` method within the `custcursor1` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to apply projection while you use your find query in this line

```
MongoCursor<Document> custcursor1 = newcustDetails.find(eq("first_name", fname)).projection(Projections.include("CustomerID")).iterator();
```

Therefore, you do not need to use secondary find query. I hope, I understand your exact problem and answer to your question.

Personally, I would recommend you to use Aggregation Pipeline instead of using find/projection, if you need to do stuff step by step.